I m unable to see column data type nor in list there is not settings for column and in list setting column is not visible
I have a column called category and i want to see the data type and when i m clicking on it setting option is not available. I checked in list settings as well there no column visible with the name of category.
Major issue it is used for dynamic filtering in one of the page and when i m clicking on it is redirecting to item properties and we disable redirection?

Ensure that you have the necessary permissions to view list settings.  You need to have at least Edit permission level.
